# Visual studio Online : how to Strcuture

Tags: azure-devops

I have a common DataAccess Class Library Project. This project needs to be Referenced in multiple Visual Studio Solution.

Currently we are Referencing this DA Library via Folder created in each project called binary.

so whenever there is a change in DataAccess Library project, we have Manually update all the projects that are Referencing this DAL.

I was thinking about creating Single Solution, which will have All the Projects
including DAL & all other Projects that are Referencing it and change the Reference to PRoject Reference DAL from other Projects, instead of File Reference from Binary folder.

Is there any other Better Solution around sharing this DAL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Nuget.

You should package you dal output as a nuget package and push it to a nuget server.a nuget server can be a network share our an application like ProGet.

Preferably you have an automated build do there package and push. That makes it easy.

Then each of your other solutions can take a dependency on that package. When you update it in the Nuget server each of the solutions will notify of a new version that can be used.